set -o xtrace for just one line?
bash 4.4.20(1) on RHEL 8.4.
set -x ; ./blarge ; set +x works, of course, but it's just that much more stuff to remember to remove when you're finished.  And gets sticky if you're running ssh, sudo, etc.
Thus, as mentioned in the Subject, is there some way to tell set -x to work just on one line, as FOO=bar ./blarge sets the FOO variable to barge just for that one execution of blarge?
declare Srv=s1.example.com
declare DB=a_db
declare Tables="-t table1 -t table2"

date +"%F %T, %a Starting"
set -x
vacuumdb --host=$Srv -j2 --dbname=$DB $Tables --analyze
set +x
date +"%F %T, %a Finished"


as for my humble opinion, I would not complicate things with subshell as Stephen pointed out, good alternative, since you require some, but set +x afterward is better option, opinion-based of course.

Your code lack quoting, and that Tables variable should be an array, not a single string.

@Kusalananda why should I go through the complication of making an array, when a string works?  And the unquoted variables Just Work, too.

Because an array is the storage structure you should use for multiple separate strings? Because relying on the shell to split a string into substrings is inelegant. Because it's a bad habit that in many cases leads to code that breaks as soon as input is no longer "nice".  But you do you, obviously.

@Kusalananda look carefully at the code, and consider that maybe it does exactly what I want it to do: add -t table1 -t table2 to the vacuumdb command line.

It does, I know. That's not the point. I made the points in my previous comment.

@Kusalananda you still miss the point that "-t table1 -t table2" are not separate strings.  It's one string.

When you use the variable with vacuumdb, the shell splits it up into multiple strings. In fact, you rely on the shell doing this. If you had quoted the variable, your code would break.

@RonJohn, sure, the unquoted expansion of a space-separated string works, as long as the values you want to split the string to don't themselves contain whitespace or glob characters. It's not much more work to write Tables=(-t table1 -t table2)  and "${Tables[@]}" instead. It's not really a question of it not working in this particular case, but of the dozens and likely hundreds of questions on the site about cases where people try to apply the "simple" solution to cases where it doesn't work, and then just complain instead of just doing it right in the first place.

Anyway, you don't need declare there either, and the whole script would work in any POSIX sh, not only Bash, if you just dropped the keyword entirely. (Granted, arrays wouldn't work in a pure POSIX sh either, but at least they do work in some other shells besides Bash.)

@ilkkachu those table names will never have spaces in them. EVER.  Thus the quotes and array are massive overkill.  declare is a standard practice of mine.  As for declare not being POSIX-compliant... the UNIX Wars are over.  "Linux" won, and Corporate Linux all have bash installed.

@RonJohn, I don't know anything about wars, but it sounds like you're living one. Anyway, you might want to consider looking at zsh, it has less of those traditional misfeatures, and a saner syntax for arrays.

There are a couple of approaches you can use if you wrap it up in a function.  This is useful because you can then re-use the function to make multiple such one-line calls.  It would also allow for cleaner code.
NB - These work in bash, ymmv with other shells.
xtrace() (
  set -x
  "${@}"
)

Note the use of ( ) instead of { }, which makes the entire function run in a subshell -- thus any changes to set (and variables) will live and die within the function.
xtrace() {
  local -
  set -x
  "${@}"
}

Declaring local - localises any changes made via set within the containing function.  This would be a useful approach if you want to make persistent changes to variables that are available within the function's scope.
In either case, you would call it like so:
xtrace ./blarge
xtrace ./foo bar "b a z"

If you want to enable xtrace for a longer block of commands, you could just wrap the commands up in their own function and call it with the xtrace function.

You could use a subshell:
(set -x; ./blarge)

This ensures that -x is only set for the duration of the subshell.

Interesting.  I edited my question to add the actual code.  Will that inherit my shell variables (or do I need to export them)?

Yes, subshells inherit shell variables without exporting them.

Then I'll give that a try.  Too bad vim sets everything in parens the same color...
